# MySQL Workbench can see schema but not query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running a `MySQL` Database on Amazon RDS (AWS). I have a Tomcat Server that can access the Database, so I know the Database is fine.

I am using `MySQL Workbench`, and have a local `MySQL Server` running. The `MySQL Workbench` can access the local `MySQL server` fine.

Then I connect `MySQL Workbench` to the remote MySQL Database (AWS RDS). The schema is visible and I can see all the tables. However, as soon as I try run a `SQL` statement against the Database, it just hangs.  I did originally create and populate the database from the same `MySQL Workbench` connection.

I am running locally on a `MacOS`. I have to Force Quit `SQL Workbench`.

If anyone can suggest what I can do to run `SQL` I would appreciate the advise.

Comment: Test running a simple SQL statement. such as `SELECT 1` to see if that returns or hangs. If that works, then try a very simple query against one of your tables which is guaranteed to return an empty set. `SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE 0=1`. See if that hangs as well. My guess (just a guess) is those will work, and its the SQL statement you are attempting to execute may just be taking a long time. Maybe its producing a huge intermediate set as the result of a cross product, or maybe an expensive join operation, or expensive sort operation. (Without the SQL and the EXPLAIN, we're just guessing.)

Comment: Thanks for the advise.  `SELECT 1;` works. `SELECT 1 FROM ebdb.category WHERE 0=1;` works too. `SELECT * FROM ebdb.category WHERE ID < 10;` works. `SELECT * FROM ebdb.person WHERE ID < 300;` works.  I think the difference is the `WHERE` clause. I thin limiting the result set has done the trick. I think your assumption is right. Apreciate the help.